# How to get params from url with React front end and express backend?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, react-router, express-router

I'm building an react app with an express backend. I'm now adding socket io chat functionality to the front end. Everything works as expected but now I want to access params from the url to set the socket-io channel name.

I want the user to visit `localhost:3000/foo` and the react frontend to be able to access the `foo` parameter.

What's the best way to do this?

At the moment I am serving the static files like so:

```
app.use(express.static(`${__dirname}/../client/dist`));
```

I tried to add react-router-dom with the following code but it doesnt display the page at all:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import App from './components/App.jsx';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <Route path="/:id" component={App} />
  </Router>,
  document.querySelector('#app'));
```

Whenever I add something to the end of the url (I fi type in something other than ‘/‘ the page does not display. I get the error “cannot GET  /foo”

I've also tried this but then the front end doesn't display either:

```
app.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
  console.log('-----------', req.params.id)
})
```

My ultimate goal would be to only display the chat app when a user visits `localhost:3000/chat/:channelId`

Comment: Why does the Route approach does not work? You should be able to access params in `App` from match parameter

Comment: Whenever I add something to the end of the url (I fi type in something other than ‘/‘ the page does not display. I get the error “cannot GET  /foo”

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `react-router` your approach is perfectly fine, you should be able to retrieve channel name from `match` parameter

```
const App = ({ match }) => (
  <div>
    <h2>You are listening to: {match.params.id}</h2>
  </div>
)
```

Look at https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/ambiguous-matches

Answer (score 0):

By referring the answer provided by @mavarazy. You could write it in a class and get the parameter via props.

```
export default class User extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>You are listening to: {this.props.match.params.id}</h2>
      </div>
   )
  }
```